# Kotlin tests: conditionally assert throwing exceptions in parametrized tests

Tags: testing, kotlin, syntax, junit5

I'd like to write a parametrized test in Kotlin. Depending on input parameters, the tested function should throw custom exception or it should succeed if everything is ok. I'm using JUnit Jupiter 5.3.2.

This is simplified version of what I have now (there are multiple input parameters in fact). It works, but it feels a little ugly as I need to include the tested method call twice:

```
companion object {
      @JvmStatic
      fun paramSource(): Stream<Arguments> = Stream.of(
            Arguments.of(1, true),
            Arguments.of(2, false),
            Arguments.of(3, true)
      )
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("paramSource")
open fun testMyServiceMethod(param: Int, shouldThrow: Boolean) {

      if (!shouldThrow) {
          // here the exception should not be thrown, so test will fail if it will be thrown
          myService.myMethodThrowingException(param)
      } else {
          assertThrows<MyCustomException>{
              myService.myMethodThrowingException(param)
          }
      }
}
```

Is there any better approach on this?

Comment: 1) This post should be moved to codereview.stackexchange since it is a working code and you want improvement. 2) Its a bad pattern to have conditional behaviour in your unit tests. Define two parametrized tests if you need to have two cases. 3) Unit tests don't check for NOT throwing exceptions, this a bad approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Neo pointed out, this wasn't a good idea. Right solution in this case would be to create two separate tests - one for each case of the original test.

Tests should include as little logic as possible. They should be simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily encapsulate this:

```
inline fun <reified E : Exception> assertThrowsIf(shouldThrow: Boolean, block: () -> Unit) {
    if (!shouldThrow) {
        block()
    } else {
        assertThrows<E>(block)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("paramSource")
open fun testMyServiceMethod(param: Int, shouldThrow: Boolean) {
    assertThrowsIf<MyCustomException>(shouldThrow) {
        myService.myMethodThrowingException(param)
    }
}
```